# how to define an ArrayAdapter for ListView outside oncreate due to update in Kotlin?

Tags: listview, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I try to get a ListView runnng with update after changing the listItems in Kotlin.
The simple examples I find here are working as long as I stay inside the activity_main. But trying to change items in a function i do not get the defined adapter.

my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    // access the items of the list
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
        R.layout.mylistviewitem, array)
    //val listView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.listview_1)
    myslist.setAdapter(adapter)
```

works and gives me the correct list.

But when I try to change the array in a function, I do not have access to "adapter", and thus  not to the "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()"
I try it with a simple function

```
fun myfkt() {    
    array[1]=" changed?"
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

So, the question is:
how do i define the adapter outside of the onCreate (main)function

Things like

```
var myadapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.Layout.mylistviewitem,array)
```

don't work. The compile is o.k, but the app immediatly crashes
(I really spent hours, but found no solution for Kotlin. Taking code from java-examples with converting automatically to Kotlin didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration for the adapter outside your `onCreate` function. You should then be able to access it from `myfkt()`

```
lateinit val adapter: ArrayAdapter
```

Then change your `onCreate` declaration to

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.mylistviewitem, array)
```

Unrelated to your question, you should considering RecyclerView. It's a much better alternative than ListView, since it formalizes good behavior through use of the ViewHolder pattern.

Comment: Thanks. it works with "lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<Any>".

Comment: Due to RecyclerView: for a beginner it seemed easier for me to start with listView. May be, I switch to RecyclerView. But for a simple list of strings, it is beter to keep it simple?

Comment: Absolutely, easier to start with List View, just don't forget to come back and check out RecyclerView when you get more comfortable with Android. Goodluck!